# Mysql multiple matches with left join

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i working with multiple tables(around 40) and i make a left Join for link multiple tables, the problem is in some of those tables there are multiple matches and for this rason get many rows, them i look a method for get the result more organized, because this result is sended to Javascript and the result is many tables, and many columns with `null` value .

```
MainTbl
    +-------------------+
    | id  columA columB |
    +-------------------+
    | 1    data   data  |
    | 2    data   data  |
    | 3    data   data  |
    | 4    data   data  |
    +-------------------+

     Table1
    +-------------------+
    | id  columA columB |
    +-------------------+
    | 1    data   data  |
    | 1    data   data  |
    | 1    data   data  |
    | 2    data   data  |
    +-------------------+
 Table2
    +-------------------+
    | id  columA columB |
    +-------------------+
    | 2    data   data  |
    | 2    data   data  |
    | 1    data   data  |
    | 1    data   data  |
    +-------------------+
```

and i make a left join like this:

```
SELECT blah,blah,blah
FROM MainTbl
LEFT JOIN  Table1 ON  Table1.Id = MainTbl.Id
LEFT JOIN  Table2 ON  Table2.Id = MainTbl.Id
...
...
..
LEFT JOIN  Table40 ON  Table40.Id = MainTbl.Id
```

**Other option** i see is make a select for each ID, and organize it by table, example
`select * from table1 where id='1'`, this result i can concat with `table2,table3...table40`, after concat subtables i can concat with main table, the result can be like this.

```
Maintbl[
        MainA:'data',
        MainA:'data',
        Table1:[
                items:[
                        subT1:[
                              Sub_subT1:data,
                              Sub_subT1:data
                               ],
                        subT1:[
                              Sub_subT1:data,
                              Sub_subT1:data
                               ],
                        subT1:[
                              Sub_subT1:data,
                              Sub_subT1:data
                               ]
                        ]
                 ],
          Table2:[
                items:[
                        subT2:[
                              Sub_subT2:data,
                              Sub_subT2:data
                               ],
                        subT2:[
                              Sub_subT2:data,
                              Sub_subT2:data
                               ],
                        subT2:[
                              Sub_subT2:data,
                              Sub_subT2:data
                               ]
                        ]
                 ]   

]
```

but I see a problem "resource consumption", because i need to work with 40 tables, and that is 40 selects, i dont know if this method is better o not, but i no see other solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: yes, i try group by id but, only get 1 row, with first ocurrence

Comment: If that's not something you'd consider, then you should start working on the breakage of the query statement. Maybe you don't need to execute 1 query per table, try to break it into 4 different queries with 10 joins each and move on from there.

Comment: I'm curious, what kind of system has a table linked with 40 others to work with itens? I'm assuming that this is not a `user` table with some kind of audit system. Other than that I fell like this is a bad database design.

Comment: this is not the fact but I'll raise well, imagine a user with 40 different skills , each skill has different parameters (columns), and where some skills have multiple characteristics (eg if your life is x will attack y), I wonder how you would make the design of your database ??