# Mysql Varchar Length and performance

Tags: php, mysql

i have a question and is about the performance and optimization, because i want save a `Json array` in mysql, this data sometimes is litle 1-5 chars but sometimes are midle maybe 70-100 chars, So my question is if there is no problem of consumption, because many data are to collect and send to javascript, around (500 rows), I want to know how I can avoid using excessive resources, without affecting the performance (avoid cuts data)

Comment: 500rows in your array, or 500 records in the db? 500 db records is **NOTHING**. 500 rows in the array, well, then it depends on just how many records you're going to have.

Comment: 500 rows of result, in my db i have around 100k records

Comment: save json string in database is very bad idea in most cases. not because of performance but just it is very often seems like if you save images instead of text ;-) You can do that but it seems weird. and one day You will face with problems how to parse and effectively manipulate with data stored.

Comment: now i have a big problem,  i want try to organize my DB [check this post please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193287/mysql-multiple-matches-with-left-join?noredirect=1#comment54194258_33193287)

Comment: @Alex and OP, MySQL 5.7.8 has a new JSON type that is very efficient at storing and searching. If you want to store your data in JSON format, consider upgrading

Comment: @rjdown interesting didn't hear about that option yet, could you send me a link to documentation about these new features please?

Comment: @Alex i dont think in problems for manipulate the store data, i think `json_decode` can solve all, any way, i can store a `serialize` and no problem, but my question is, if i save 1000 chars in 1 column, and this table have 100k records, without use left join, performance is lower or higher than what I have now(using leftjoin)?

Comment: @Alex https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 500 rows, you don't need to worry about performance on any modern piece of hardware.

To answer your question more precisely, it's probably best to store json data (if you must) as text. I assume you will never need to do anything with it like sorting or filtering by it so text makes the most sense.

Comment: but are 500 rows, but i make many `left joins`, i test the performance in php and i have ( [memory] => 0.73047943115234 [seconds] => 0.089001941680908 )

Comment: @jearca you do `left join` with json saved columns in `ON` clause?

Comment: [check this post please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193287/mysql-multiple-matches-with-left-join?noredirect=1#comment54194258_33193287) here is the structure of my table, my problem is because i have many matches for 1 `id`, and i looking solution, and i think in save a array(json), when many matches is aviable